# Geoserver ImagePyramids problem with WMS request in different projection

Tags: projection, geoserver, wms

In Geoserver I have Image Pyramid in  EPSG 28992 ( RD New )

The pyramid (as wms service) works fijn when added to the map (QGIS project) in RD New projection.

When added to the QGIS map in another projection: WGS84 (EPSG: 4326) I get the time out error/ (in de log: out of memory error) and I have to restart de geoserver.

I notice the same behaviour in ArcMap.

- Geoserver version 2.14.4 / 2.13.3
- pyramids made with gdal_retile :

  > gdal_retile -v -r bilinear -levels 6 -ps 1024 1024 -co "TILED=YES"
  >   -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" -s_srs "EPSG:28992" -targetDir rce_waterstaatskrt1_pyramids_1024_6_kopie waterstaatskrt1.tif
- The definition of EPSG 28992 in .prj files in every pyramid directory is the same like definition of this EPSG in geoserver.
- In Geoserver log file I see that the geoserver is looking for the .prj file for each tile in each
  pyramid directory, ie.

> 2019-12-13 12:27:42,224 DEBUG [gce.imagepyramid] -
>   /srv/bigdata_data/rce_waterstaatskrt1_pyramids_1024_6_kopie/0/waterstaatskrt1_56_52.prj
>   (No such file or directory)

- another error I see:

> 2019-12-13 12:27:42,229 TRACE [geotools.factory] - THROW 
>   (CRSAuthorityFactory, CRS_AUTHORITY_FACTORY): could not find
>   implementation. 2019-12-13 12:27:42,230 DEBUG [referencing.factory] -
>   Failure in the primary factory: No code "EPSG:28992" from authority
>   "European Petroleum Survey Group" found for object of type
>   "IdentifiedObject". Now trying the fallback factory...

I am missing something? Does geoserver support 'on fly' reprojection of ImagePyramids ?

EDIT:
JVM parameters:   -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

## wildfly server

Geoserver log with first time memory error after a clean start :

```
> Server:testing04]      at
> io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
> [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final] [Server:testing04]      at
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final] [Server:testing04]      at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
> [Server:testing04]      at
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final] [Server:testing04]      at
> io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final] [Server:testing04]      at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
> [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final] [Server:testing04]     
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248)
> [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final] [Server:testing04]     
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77)
> [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final] [Server:testing04]     
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167)
> [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final] [Server:testing04]     
> at
> io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
> [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final] [Server:testing04]      at
> io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761)
> [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final] [Server:testing04]      at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> [rt.jar:1.8.0_144] [Server:testing04]      at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> [rt.jar:1.8.0_144] [Server:testing04]      at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_144]
> [Server:testing04] C**aused by: org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException:
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
> [Server:testing04]      at
> org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:1200)**
> [gs-wms-2.14.4.jar:2.14.4] [Server:testing04]      at
> org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:349)
> [gs-wms-2.14.4.jar:2.14.4] [Server:testing04]      ... 141 more
> [Server:testing04] Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead
> limit exceeded [Server:testing04] [Server:testing04] [Full GC
> (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 323578K->319939K(509952K)] [ParOldGen:
> 1397305K->1396540K(1398784K)] 1720883K->1716480K(1908736K),
> [Metaspace: 128805K->128805K(1169408K)], 0.4742127 secs] [Times:
> user=0.87 sys=0.00, real=0.47 secs] [Server:testing04] [Full GC
> (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 323227K->0K(509952K)] [ParOldGen:
> 1396540K->915937K(1398784K)] 1719767K->915937K(1908736K), [Metaspace:
> 128807K->128807K(1169408K)], 0.3104434 secs] [Times: user=0.56
> sys=0.00, real=0.31 secs] [Server:testing04] [GC (Allocation Failure)
> [PSYoungGen: 323584K->123968K(507904K)] 1239521K->1039906K(1906688K),
> 0.0258102 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] [Server:testing04] [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen:
> 448369K->184316K(509952K)] 1364306K->1127905K(1908736K), 0.0341909
> secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] [Server:testing04]
> [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 509948K->118561K(473088K)]
> 1453537K->1231642K(1871872K), 0.0452980 secs] [Times: user=0.08
> sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] [Server:testing04] [GC (Allocation Failure)
> [PSYoungGen: 403233K->204932K(491520K)] 1516314K->1318022K(1890304K),
> 0.0314318 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] [Server:testing04] [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen:
> 487473K->206835K(442368K)] 1600563K->1394644K(1841152K), 0.0403641
> secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] [Server:testing04]
> [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 442355K->170269K(466944K)]
> 1630164K->1471620K(1865728K), 0.0405392 secs] [Times: user=0.08
> sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] [Server:testing04] [Full GC (Ergonomics)
> [PSYoungGen: 170269K->41155K(466944K)] [ParOldGen:
> 1301351K->1398761K(1398784K)] 1471620K->1439917K(1865728K),
> [Metaspace: 128844K->128833K(1169408K)], 0.2696253 secs] [Times:
> user=0.46 sys=0.00, real=0.27 secs] [Server:testing04] [Full GC
> (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 276675K->110407K(466944K)] [ParOldGen:
> 1398761K->1396672K(1398784K)] 1675437K->1507079K(1865728K),
> [Metaspace: 128842K->128833K(1169408K)], 0.2667960 secs] [Times:
> user=0.46 sys=0.00, real=0.27 secs] [Server:testing04] [Full GC
> (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 235520K->136542K(466944K)] [ParOldGen:
> 1396672K->1398254K(1398784K)] 1632192K->1534797K(1865728K),
> [Metaspace: 128842K->128833K(1169408K)], 0.2475386 secs] [Times:
> user=0.43 sys=0.00, real=0.25 secs] [Server:testing04] [Full GC
> (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 235520K->165582K(466944K)] [ParOldGen:
> 1398254K->1398250K(1398784K)] 1633774K->1563833K(1865728K),
> [Metaspace: 128842K->128833K(1169408K)], 0.2464697 secs] [Times:
> user=0.41 sys=0.00, real=0.25 secs]
```

Comment: If you are seeing out of memory errors - increase the memory https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/container.html#optimize-your-jvm

Comment: Thank you @IanTurton for sugestion. We try different configurations;
Configuration geoserver now:
-Heap Size:512m,-Max Heap Size:2048m,Permgen Size:512m, Max Permgen Size:2048m
-JVM Options:-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dorg.geotools.localDateTimeHandling=true -server
The log now:
15:58:20,539 INFO  [org.vfny.geoserver.servlets] (default task-18) OutputStream was successfully aborted.
[Server:testing04] 15:58:20,539 ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] (default task-18) : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.  Th

Comment: can you add the section of log file when the memory error first occurs after a clean restart? and the exact JVM params to the question using the [edit] button